# Evento Padrao Exit na tecla ESC

Tags: c#, winforms

Atualmente no meu sistema utilizo o evento `KeyPress` para identificar a tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd> e assim fechar o meu form, porém tenho um sistema bem grande com mais de 50 formulários e ainda mais sendo desenvolvidos:

Minha duvida é: Existe alguma forma padrão para setar a tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd> como *exit* do form?

Comment: Crie um form padrão que contenha essa funcionalidade e todas as outras que forem necessárias e herde todos os outros forms desse.

Comment: No caso isto seria viável somente para os novos forms correto?

Comment: @LeoLonghi Não, se você fizer com que o nome deste form (da classe) seja `Form`, isso vai valer pros que já foram criados também.

Comment: @Bacco Alguma forma de desfazer isto?

Comment: @LeoLonghi sim, só clicar em "restaurar" abaixo dela. Mas foi só uma sugestão, veja como acha melhor. Nao tem problema ter deletado, foi só uma idéia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, existem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Minha dica pra você é criar um form simples com todos os comportamentos padrões para os forms do sistema e sempre que criar um form novo, fazer com que este novo herde o form padrão.

```
public class FormPadrao : Form
{
    /* Outros métodos */

    private void form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

E o uso ficaria assim

```
public FormCadastro : FormPadrao { }
```

---

Se você precisa disso **para todos os forms**, incluindo os que já existem pode simplesmente criar uma classe chamada `Form`. Perceba que todos os *forms* atuais já herdam de uma classe chamada `Form`, então, a partir do momento que você definir uma classe com este nome, os forms atuais irão herdar o *form* que foi criado dentro do seu projeto.

Então, o `Form` padrão ficaria assim

```
public class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form { }
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isto que eu precisava! :)